# Where can I learn CGI Programming in C?

Tags: cgi

Hi I'm a student and on my internship. Unluckily, my company wants me to write CGI programming with C. I've no idea why they want to use it. Anyway I've to learn and apply it for the next 2 months. How and what can I learn CGI programming. I've 2 years experience with asp.net. Can you give me some good links too .

Thanks in advance.
Kevin

Comment: Did Google reveal nothing?  What CGI code have you looked at?  What questions did you have about the code you downloaded?

Comment: Well, I've to start coding on coming Monday. The boss told me to look some sample coding first. So I wonder anybody knows some great link.

Comment: @kevin: Are you saying that Google found you absolutely nothing you could read?  We don't know you very well.  We don't know how much you know or what you've read?  We may know the same great link you already read.  Please provide some hint as to what you've read and what code you've downloaded to save us all from wasting a lot of time guessing.

Comment: @lott>> thanks for your reply, Today i start reading CGI. I found so many links on google but don't know where i should start. I want to study some basic stuffs first.

Comment: Start with the first link you find. If that doesn't work, try the next one. Repeat.
Alternatively, since you're a student you can probably check your school's library for something CGI. The books are likely to be out of date, but CGI is an old technology and you might find something.

Comment: @kevin: "some basic stuffs first".  Can you provide us *any* hint at all?  Any clue what you think might be *basic*?

Comment: well  my boss told me that I've to write a web form and there are 2 textbox. User will type the IP address and I have to save it in a text file and run one program they have already written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As everyone else has stated Google is your friend. But, here are some links from my bookmarks which are useful.

A good tutorial is:
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html

Oreilly Has an out of print book which they freely publish online:
http://oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/ch01_06.html

Dr. Dobbs has an article:
http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403248

Linux Journal also has an article:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6863

And then there's also the cgic library:
http://www.boutell.com/cgic/

Comment: For IIS 7.0 and 7.5 users http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/how-to-run-a-cgi-program-under-iis-7-0-or-iis-7-5 .  Just compile a normal command line style C program instead of the C# example given.

Comment: I've tried taking back my -1, it was a long time ago and I was more ignorant. IIR the reason i did it was meaningless and I'll remove it if this answer gets edited. That being said, you could have stood to drop a BIT of theory in there not just links I'm sure. Though that is essentially what OP asked for.